using a tikz foreach loop inside a newcommand
I want to make a newcommand which uses a foreach loop in tikz to draw lines, whose points are parameterized in the newcommand. I am running into two problems:

If no unit is specified when calling my command, it says that I am using an illegal unit of measurement (pt).
If I specify the unit as centimeters (cm), then the compilation times out.

Here is an MWE
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\xLines}[2]{
% Draws parallel vertical lines.
% #1  - xmin
% #2  - xmax
\foreach \Vx in {#1+0.2,#1+0.4,...,#2-0.2}{\draw (\Vx,-5) -- (\Vx,5);}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\xLines{-1}{6}}
\end{document}


You need to evaluate the arguments of \foreach, there is a key for that, but I forgot its name... (someone might chime in)

Looked up the correct key in the documentation. If you want to use expressions inside your last element of your \foreach-list that need to be evaluated you should specify the parse key:
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\xLines}[2]{
% Draws parallel vertical lines.
% #1  - xmin
% #2  - xmax
\foreach[parse=true] \Vx in {#1+0.2,#1+0.4,...,#2-0.2}{\draw (\Vx,-5) -- (\Vx,5);}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\xLines{-1}{6}}
\end{document}

With this you'll get #1+0.2 for the first \Vx, #1+0.4 as the second, and starting from there the result of #1 + n * 0.2 (so in the example above with -1 and 6 you'll get -1+0.2, -1+0.4, -0.4, -0.2, ..., 5.8 -- with slight rounding errors).
If you for some reason need also the evaluation of #1+0.2 and #1+0.4 inside \Vx (not the case here since you're feeding it into spots in which pgf/TikZ will eventually evaluate them) you should additionally specify evaluate=\Vx, so \foreach[parse=true, evaluate=\Vx] ....

I appreciate the swift aid, this syntax will actually be very useful in future diagrams of mine. Thank you

I just noticed this, but both of our codes raise the warning Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont! due to the unnecessary semicolon. Would it be okay to edit the question and answer to omit this semicolon?

@Jasper of course.

I edited the answer, feel free to make any changes you see fit.
